# If one combobox is changed, reset the other combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have two activeX comboboxes on a sheet: One for month and one for quarter.
The month combobox includes a "---" option which is representative of no month selected.
I also use the "---" character in the quarter combobox.

I would like if the user selects a month, not "---", the quarter box resets to "---".
Similarly, if the user selects a quarter, the month combobox should reset to "---".

My code in the sheet ("shDashboard" is the CodeName of the sheet. The boxes are named Quarter_Combo and Month_Combo.):

```vb
Private Sub Month_Combo_Change()
    MsgBox "Month_Combo"
    shDashboard.Quarter_Combo.Value = "—" 
End Sub

Private Sub Quarter_Combo_Change()
    MsgBox "Quarter_Combo"
    shDashboard.Month_Combo.Value = shDashboard.Month_Combo.List(0)
End Sub
```

The message boxes are there to help troubleshoot.
When I change the month, it will update the quarter combobox which in turn will update the month combo box.
The result is that both boxes display "---".

I tried `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.EnableEvents` doesn't work in this case. Here is a workaround

```
Private pbDisableComboEvents As Boolean

Private Sub Month_Combo_Change()
    If Not pbDisableComboEvents Then
        MsgBox "Month_Combo"
        pbDisableComboEvents = True
        Me.Quarter_Combo.Value = "-"
        pbDisableComboEvents = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Quarter_Combo_Change()
    If Not pbDisableComboEvents Then
        MsgBox "Quarter_Combo"
        pbDisableComboEvents = True
        Me.Month_Combo.Value = "-"
        pbDisableComboEvents = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks for the help!